# hibernate.ejb.interceptor not 'intercepting', Spring+JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring, tomcat, jpa, interceptor

Folks- I am trying to set up hibernate.ejb.interceptor but for some reason it never gets to 'intercept' any update or insert event. The application seems to work fine, updating and inserting entities but no interception.

I cannot find what is wrong with my setup, please help:

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"
                value="my.AuditLogInterceptor" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="false" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myDS" jndi-name="jdbc/myDS"
        resource-ref="true" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="myEMF"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDS" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEMF" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDS" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="auditLog" class="my.AuditLog" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

Interceptor (From manning book):

```
public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -634733855120326803L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory
            .getXLogger(AuditLogInterceptor.class.getName());

    private Session session;
    private Long userId;
    private Set<Auditable> inserts = new HashSet<Auditable>();
    private Set<Auditable> updates = new HashSet<Auditable>();

    public AuditLogInterceptor() {}

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        logger.entry(entity, id, state, propertyNames);

        if (entity instanceof Auditable)
            inserts.add((Auditable) entity);

        logger.exit();

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id,
            Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        logger.entry(entity, id, currentState, previousState);

        if (entity instanceof Auditable)
            updates.add((Auditable) entity);

        logger.exit();

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) throws CallbackException {
        logger.entry(iterator);

        try {
            for (Auditable entity : inserts) {
                AuditLog.logEvent("create", entity, "userId");
            }           

            for (Auditable entity : inserts) {
                new AuditLog().logEvent("update", entity, "userId");
            }

        } finally {
            inserts.clear();
            updates.clear();
        }

        logger.exit();
    }
}
```

The Spring bean (found it on the web):

```
public class AuditLog {

    static protected AuditLog theAuditLog = null;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    protected EntityManager itsEntityManager;

    public AuditLog() {
        theAuditLog = this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the entity manager
     */
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return this.itsEntityManager;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return Hibernate Session
     */
    protected Session getHibernateSession() {
        return (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
    }

    public static void logEvent(String action, Auditable entity, String userId) {
        /*
         * TODO get rid of this .connection() - deprecated - call !
         */
        Session tempSession = theAuditLog.getHibernateSession()
                .getSessionFactory()
                .openSession(theAuditLog.getHibernateSession().connection());

        try {
            AuditLogRecord alr = new AuditLogRecord();
            alr.entityId = entity.getId();
            alr.entityClass = entity.getClass();
            alr.message = "Something changed";
            alr.created = new Date();

            tempSession.save(alr);
            tempSession.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CallbackException(ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                tempSession.close();
            } catch (HibernateException ex) {
                throw new CallbackException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using JPA annotation based interceptors like @PrePersist, @PostPersist, etc??

Comment: Removed Tomcat based (inside context.xml) data source set up and moved it to spring (myservlet-servlet.xml) and it started to work.